# Find and show partial text in mysql query

Tags: mysql, find

I have one mysql table that has a column that is "description".
In this column, some descriptions contain a word "peso" (this word can be "Peso", "peso", "PESO" but i need all the results).

What i need is one query that gives me all the rows that contains that word in the description text and show in another column on the result the partial text of the description starting in this word.

How can i do it? I don't have fulltext search.

Comment: select * from table
where description like "%peso%"

Comment: this is a part of my question, the hard part is "show in another column on the result the partial text of the description starting in this word"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do:

```
select substring(description, instr(lower(description), 'peso'))) as rest_of_string
from table
where lower(description) like '%peso%';
```

I'm adding the lower because you might be using a case-sensitive collation.